# Trig. Indefinite Integral $\int\frac{\tan x +\tan ^3 x}{1+\tan^3 x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$\displaystyle \int\frac{\tan x +\tan ^3 x}{1+\tan^3 x}dx$

$\underline{\bf{My \; Try}}$:: Let $\tan x = t$. Then $\sec^2 xdx = dt\Rightarrow \displaystyle dx = \frac{1}{1+\tan^2 t}dt\Rightarrow dx = \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$

So $\displaystyle \int\frac{t+t^3}{1+t^3}\cdot \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt = \int\frac{t}{1+t^3}dt$

Now My Question is can we solve the Given Integral without Using Partial fraction Method

If Yes How can I solve

plz Help me , Thanks

Comment: The Maple command $$Student[Calculus1]:-IntTutor((tan(x)+tan(x)^3)/(1+tan(x)^3), x) $$ outputs $$1/6\,\ln  \left(  \left( \tan \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}-\tan
 \left( x \right) +1 \right) +1/3\,\sqrt {3}\arctan \left( 1/3\,\sqrt 
{3} \left( 2\,\tan \left( x \right) -1 \right)  \right) -1/3\,\ln 
 \left( \tan \left( x \right) +1 \right) 
 $$ step by step with explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica evaluates it as 
$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \tan (x)-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{6} \log \left(\tan ^2(x)-\tan (x)+1\right)-\frac{1}{3} \log (\tan (x)+1)$$
This can be done via partial fractions.
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{t}{1 + t^3} \; dt &= \frac 1 3 \int \frac{t+1}{t^2 - t + 1} dt - \frac 1 3 \int \frac{1}{1+t} \; dt\\ 
 &= \frac 1 3 \int \frac{t+1}{ \left ( t - \frac 1 2 \right )^2 + \frac 3 4} \; dt - \frac 1 3 \log(1+t)\\ 
 &=  \frac 1 3  \int \frac{t - \frac 1 2  + \frac 3 2 }{ \left ( t - \frac 1 2 \right )^2 + \frac 3 4} \; dt - \frac 1 3 \log(1+t)\\ 
 &= \frac 1 6 \log \left(  \left ( t - \frac 1 2 \right )^2 + \frac 3 4 \right ) - \frac 1  3 \log(1+t) + \frac 1 2 \int \frac{1}{ \left ( t - \frac 1 2 \right )^2 + \frac 3 4}\;  dt \\ 
 &= \frac 1 6 \log \left(  \left ( t - \frac 1 2 \right )^2 + \frac 3 4 \right ) - \frac 1  3 \log(1+t)  + \frac 1 {\sqrt{3}} \arctan \left( \frac{t - \frac 1 2 }{ \frac{\sqrt 3}{2 } } \right ) 
\end{align*}

Comment: @amWhy after replacing $t = \tan(x)$ I get 
$$ \frac 1 6 \log( \tan(x)^2 - \tan(x) + 1) - \frac1 3 \log(1+\tan(x)) + \frac 1{\sqrt 3 } \arctan( (2 \tan(x)- 1)/\sqrt 3 )$$
I think i should get eye check up. could you point out where it is not matching?

Comment: No, it matches.  Just multiply by $2$ inside the $\arctan$ term to get $2t-1\over \sqrt 3$ inside.

Answer (score 4):

Good work up to now. But now we do need to use partial fractions; that is the most straightforward approach:

$$\dfrac t{t^3 + 1} = \dfrac t{(t+1)(t^2 - t + 1)} = \dfrac{A}{t+1} + \dfrac {Bt + C}{t^2 - t + 1}$$

Comment: Let me know if you can take it from here.

Comment: Your coefficients should be $A = - \frac 13$, $B = C = \frac 13$

Comment: very clean answer +1

Answer (score 4):

**Addendum:**

Evaluating $ \displaystyle{\int\frac{t}{t^3 + 1}\,\mathrm{d}t} $ without partial fractions:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\frac{t}{t^3 + 1}\,\mathrm{d}t&=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{t+1+t-1}{t^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{t+1}{(t+1)(t^2-t+1)}\,\mathrm{d}t-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{t^2 - t + 1 - t^2}{t^3 + 1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\left(t-1/2\right)^2 + \left(\sqrt{3}/2\right)^2} - \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t+1} + \frac{1}{6}\int\frac{3t^2}{t^3 + 1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{2t-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\log\left|t+1\right| + \frac{1}{6}\log\left|t^3 + 1\right| + C.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: You used what essentially amounts to partial fractions in the second and third lines, though...

Answer (score 1):

Partial fractions can be avoided altogether while still utilizing a trigonometric substitution. Let

$$y = \frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x} \implies x = \arctan \frac{1-y}{1+y} = \frac\pi4 - \arctan y,$$

which yields

$$\begin{align*}
& \int \frac{\tan x + \tan^3x}{1 + \tan^3x} \, dx \\
&= \int \frac{\frac{1-y}{1+y} + \frac{(1-y)^3}{(1+y)^3}}{1 + \frac{(1-y)^3}{(1+y)^3}} \cdot \frac{-dy}{1+y^2} \\
&= \int \frac{y-1}{3y^2+1} \, dy \\
&= \frac16 \log\left(3y^2+1\right) - \frac1{\sqrt3} \arctan\left(\sqrt 3\,y\right) + C
\end{align*}$$

Below is a comparison of the antiderivative obtained with $y=\tan x$ and $y=\dfrac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}$; for the convenient choice of $C=0$, the former produces a constant imaginary part, while the latter is real and continuous over each period.

[image]